# Set on click listener to a button in a list view Android

Tags: android, listview, button, row, onclicklistener

I'm creating an item order list for a restaurrant.
The goal is to set onClickListener to each button(+/-) in each row in the list so it can count how many items are ordered.
Can anyone please help me with this code? i have managed to set a listener but it does not count the items properly when clicking among the rows.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] item_names = {"Mozza Cheese", "Chicken Rings", "Onion Rings", "Calamari Rings"};
    private int item_counter = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_order_list);

        listAdapter();

    }

    private void listAdapter(){
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.items_name_order, item_names));

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);

        }
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_order, parent, false);

            TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_name_order);
            final TextView item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_item_order);

            Button plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_plus_order);
            Button minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_minus_order);

            item_name.setText(item_names[position]);

            plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    item_counter++;
                    item_count.setText(Integer.toString(item_counter));

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is view_order.xml?

Comment: why do you have only one int with counter? there should be few separated counters (probably array with same length/size) for each `item_name`, yes? also you are setting text for `item_count` `TextView` only inside `OnClickListener`, list will redraw and this text will dissapear. you should read about `ListView` behaviour (recycling views especially and `notifyDataSetChanged()` method)

Comment: You have a single `item_counter` variable that is shared with every item and you are not saving the item count to a backing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note new int array `item_counter`, rest as in my comment to question

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] item_names = {"Mozza Cheese", "Chicken Rings", "Onion Rings", "Calamari Rings"};
    private int[] item_counter = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_order_list);

        listAdapter();

    }

    private void listAdapter(){
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.items_name_order, item_names));

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);

        }
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_order, parent, false);

            TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_name_order);
            final TextView item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_item_order);

            Button plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_plus_order);
            Button minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_minus_order);

            item_name.setText(item_names[position]);
            item_count.setText(item_counter[position];
            plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    item_counter[position]++;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works just fine now, notifyDataSetChanged() method save all  the hassles